# Set values to NA in data frame if Date is outside of a given interval

Tags: r, dataframe, apply, lapply

I have two dataframes, `df1` and `df2`.

`df1` contains values for different products `X1`,`X2`,and so on at different times. `df2` contains the true start and end date for some of the products. I want to replace the values outside of the given date intervals in `df2` by `NA`, as shown in the final table `df3`.

Create `df1` and `df2`:

```
df1=data.frame(matrix(NA,10,6))
df1[,1]=(c(seq(as.Date("2012-01-01"),as.Date("2012-10-01"),by="1 month")))
df1[,2]=c(1:10); df1[,3]=c(12:21); df1[,4]=c(0.5:10); df1[,5]=c(5:14); df1[,6]=c(10:19)
colnames(df1)=c("Date","X1","X2","X3","X4","X5")
df2=data.frame(matrix(data=c("X1","X2","X4","2012-02-01","2012-04-01","2012-06-01","2012-09-01","2012-06-01","2012-10-01"),3,3))
colnames(df2)=c("Name","Start","End")
```

Output:

```
   > df1
         Date X1 X2  X3 X4 X5
1  2012-01-01  1 12 0.5  5 10
2  2012-02-01  2 13 1.5  6 11
3  2012-03-01  3 14 2.5  7 12
4  2012-04-01  4 15 3.5  8 13
5  2012-05-01  5 16 4.5  9 14
6  2012-06-01  6 17 5.5 10 15
7  2012-07-01  7 18 6.5 11 16
8  2012-08-01  8 19 7.5 12 17
9  2012-09-01  9 20 8.5 13 18
10 2012-10-01 10 21 9.5 14 19
> df2
  Name      Start        End
1   X1 2012-02-01 2012-09-01
2   X2 2012-04-01 2012-06-01
3   X4 2012-06-01 2012-10-01
```

Final output should look like this:

```
 df3
       Date  X1  X2  X3 X4 X5
1  2012-01-01 NA NA 0.5 NA 10
2  2012-02-01  2 NA 1.5 NA 11
3  2012-03-01  3 NA 2.5 NA 12
4  2012-04-01  4 15 3.5 NA 13
5  2012-05-01  5 16 4.5 NA 14
6  2012-06-01  6 17 5.5 10 15
7  2012-07-01  7 NA 6.5 11 16
8  2012-08-01  8 NA 7.5 12 17
9  2012-09-01  9 NA 8.5 13 18
10 2012-10-01 NA NA 9.5 14 19
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dplyr` and `tidyr`...

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df3 <- df1 %>% gather(key=Name,value=value,-Date) %>% #convert to long form
  left_join(df2) %>% #merge in date limits
  mutate(ind=(as.Date(Date)>=as.Date(Start) & as.Date(Date)<=as.Date(End))) %>% #check valid 
  mutate(value=replace(value,!ind,NA)) %>% #replace invalid with NA
  select(Date,Name,value) %>% #remove unnecessary variables
  spread(key=Name,value=value) #convert back to rectangular form

df3
         Date X1 X2  X3 X4 X5
1  2012-01-01 NA NA 0.5 NA 10
2  2012-02-01  2 NA 1.5 NA 11
3  2012-03-01  3 NA 2.5 NA 12
4  2012-04-01  4 15 3.5 NA 13
5  2012-05-01  5 16 4.5 NA 14
6  2012-06-01  6 17 5.5 10 15
7  2012-07-01  7 NA 6.5 11 16
8  2012-08-01  8 NA 7.5 12 17
9  2012-09-01  9 NA 8.5 13 18
10 2012-10-01 NA NA 9.5 14 19
```

Comment: That looks pretty good. I'll try it on the real data, thank you!

Comment: That's a relief! Happy to help

Answer (score 1):

I am sure there is a more elegant way, but you could create a matrix of the indices that meet your criterion, where you set the elements to `1` if it is within your interval for that product and `NA` if it isn't. Assuming you are dealing with numerical values you can then multiply your data frame with that index matrix:

**Example:**

```
library(dplyr)
## Convert your dates to Date-objects:
df2 <- df2 %>% dplyr::mutate(Start = as.Date(Start), End = as.Date(End))

## Create a matrix of indices (TRUE/FALSE):
indMx <- lapply(names(df1)[-1], function(product){
            (df1$Date >= df2$Start[df2$Name == product]) & 
                    (df1$Date <= df2$End[df2$Name == product]) 
        }) %>% do.call('cbind',.)

## Multiply with NA^indMx, which gives you NA in place of FALSE and 
## 1 in place of TRUE:
df1[,-1] <- df1[,-1]*NA^indMx

df1
#          Date X1 X2  X3
# 1  2012-01-01  1 12 0.5
# 2  2012-02-01 NA 13 1.5
# 3  2012-03-01 NA 14 2.5
# 4  2012-04-01 NA NA 3.5
# 5  2012-05-01 NA NA 4.5
# 6  2012-06-01 NA NA  NA
# 7  2012-07-01 NA 18  NA
# 8  2012-08-01 NA 19  NA
# 9  2012-09-01 NA 20  NA
# 10 2012-10-01 10 21  NA
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I encountered a new problem, so I updated the initial post for clarification. Not sure if I need to make edits to the code to make it work on the new issue.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution with `data.table`. There might be a more elegant method using non-equi joins.

```
for(i in seq_len(nrow(df2))) df1[!(Date %between% df2[i,.(Start, End)]), df2[i, Name] := NA]
```

Here, you run through each row of df2, subset df1 based on dates outside of the start and end dates in the current row of df2, and then assign NA to the variable given in df2.

This returns

```
df1
          Date X1 X2  X3
 1: 2012-01-01 NA NA  NA
 2: 2012-02-01  2 NA  NA
 3: 2012-03-01  3 NA  NA
 4: 2012-04-01  4 15  NA
 5: 2012-05-01  5 16  NA
 6: 2012-06-01  6 17 5.5
 7: 2012-07-01  7 NA 6.5
 8: 2012-08-01  8 NA 7.5
 9: 2012-09-01  9 NA 8.5
10: 2012-10-01 NA NA 9.5
```

---

*update*

If the data is constructed as was updated in the original post, then run this line first to convert the Names variable in df2 to a character vector (starts out as a factor). Then the above code will work for the new dataset.

```
# convert data.frames to data.tables
setDT(df1)
setDT(df2)

# convert factor to character
df2[, Name := as.character(Name)]
```

---

**data**

```
library(data.table)
# read in data
df1 <- fread("Date X1 X2  X3
2012-01-01  1 12 0.5
2012-02-01  2 13 1.5
2012-03-01  3 14 2.5
2012-04-01  4 15 3.5
2012-05-01  5 16 4.5
2012-06-01  6 17 5.5
2012-07-01  7 18 6.5
2012-08-01  8 19 7.5
2012-09-01  9 20 8.5
2012-10-01 10 21 9.5")

df2 <- fread("  Name      Start        End
X1 2012-02-01 2012-09-01
X2 2012-04-01 2012-06-01
X3 2012-06-01 2012-10-01")

# convert to date type
df1[, Date := as.Date(Date)]
df2[, c("Start", "End")  := .(as.Date(Start), as.Date(End))]
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I encountered a new problem, so I updated the initial post for clarification.

Comment: See update section. df$Name is a factor in your data and must be converted to a character vector.

Comment: Nice! I'll try it out.